# how to fixed the loop outcome with continue

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to use a `for` loop for 10 questions with an if condition. The `continue` is used to pass the one which is not match with condition.

My purpose is to randomly come up 10 question equations which results should be integers, but my code gives me only correct condition with a variable number of questions.

When the condition is not met, it will pass current equation, therefore sometimes I have end up with only 5 or 7 questions because the other 5 or 3 did not pass the condition.

How can I make sure that number of random equation generate is always the same, so that if a the condition is not met, the function will redo random amount of actions to end up with **10** questions?

my code is :

```
<body>
<p>this is testing for random number meet creteria</p>

<button class = "button" onclick = "myFunction()">try me</button>

<p id = "demo">Thisis where to display question</p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var quiz = "";
        var xNumber;
        var yNumber;
        var sign = ["+", "-", "*", "/"];
      
        for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
            var xNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
            var yNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
            var randomSign = sign[Math.floor(Math.random()*sign.length)];
            var result = eval(xNumber + randomSign + yNumber);

            if (Number.isInteger(result)) {
                quiz += xNumber + randomSign + yNumber + "<br>";
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }            
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = quiz;  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your `for` loop is going to execute exactly 10 times, and on each iteration it will _either_ produce an equation _or_ `continue` (do nothing). You don't want to iterate exactly 10 times, you want to iterate _until_ you have 10 equations, which is what John Tyner's answer does. Separately, I suggest you get comfortable with using `let` and `const` instead of `var`.

Comment: Thanks, I will take your advice and try a different way. appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loop to be conditional on getting the number of items you want.

```
var numQuestions = 10, counter = 0
while (counter < numQuestions) {
            var xNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
            var yNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
            var randomSign = sign[Math.floor(Math.random()*sign.length)];
            var result = eval(xNumber + randomSign + yNumber);

            if (Number.isInteger(result)) {
                quiz += xNumber + randomSign + yNumber + "<br>";
                // increment your counter here since you've added another question
                counter ++;
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for that John Tyner, it really help, it solved my problem.